# Java Int[] Array returning bytes. Why?

Tags: java, byte

//turns a string of integers into an int[] array
// reversed is the name of the string of integers

Here is the code:

```
    public int[] makeintArray(){
          intArray = new int[reversed.length()];
          for (int i = 0; i < reversed.length(); i++){
              intArray[i] = reversed.charAt(i) - 48;
              System.out.println("int " + i + " is " + intArray[i]);
  }
  System.out.println("IntArray is: " + intArray);
  return intArray;
```

}

//Whenever I run this I get the integer array returned as "cf814a82@I[" rather than [3, 3, 8, 2, 3, 8, 2, 8]

Comment: Change `intArray[i] = reversed.charAt(i) - 48;` to `intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt("" + reversed.charAr(i));`

Comment: @MiłoszTomkiel that didn't work. Same result.

Comment: I'm using this and it works: `int[] intArrayFromString(String str) {
  int[] arr = new int[str.length()];
  for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = Integer.parseInt("" + str.charAt(i));
  }
  return arr;
}`